# Lead is not flowing from Linked Lead Gen Form

Tags: trigger, leads, campaign, sales-cloud, linkedin

I have configured the LinkedIn Lead Gen as per guidelines in [Release Note](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_sales_features_core_leads_linkedin_integration.htm?edition=&impact=). And also I am running the campaign on LinkedIn that are capturing the leads. The lead count is increasing in the LinkedIn campaign but neither leads are not created into Salesforce nor I am getting any error email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that **Require reCAPTCHA Verification** was checked at Web-to-Lead Setup page in my org. It prevents LinkedIn leads to enter into Salesforce.